# Solve heat equation given conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

> [image]

I don't quite understand what I am supposed to do with the last given condition $u(x,0)$.

I solved for all the different cases of $λ$ and got that
$$u(x,t) = e^{-3n^2π^2t}(Bsin(nπx)) $$

where $B≠0$

From here I get confused. In our answer key it simply says:

> In order to satisfy the boundary conditions we let: [image]

I would appreciate it if someone could explain what is done in the last step. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you $u(x,t)$ is correct? I would suspect that it would be $\cos$ instead of $\sin$...

Comment: Yeah, I just calculated the problem and $X(x)$ is of the form $a_n\cos(\mu x)$

Answer (score 1):

According to my calculation,

$u(x,t) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n cos(n\pi x)e^{-3(n\pi)^2t}$

Using the given initial condition, we can know that

When $n = 3 \rightarrow a_3 = 2$ 
and $n=5 \rightarrow a_5 = 4$. and $a_n = 0$ otherwise.

Therefore, $u(x,t) = 2\cos(3\pi x)e^{-3(9\pi^2)t} \ + 4\cos(5\pi x)e^{-3(25 \pi^2)t}$

Comment: How did you get that $X(x)$ is cos instead of sin?

Comment: I thought that if $X(0)=0$ then $Acos(0)+Bsin(0)=0$ → $A=0$, so then for
$X(1)=0$ the A term is removed and $Bsin(α)=0$ where $α=nπ$.
Thus, $X(x)=Bsin(nπx)$ but now I understand that in order to satisfy $u(x,t)$ I should have gotten cos. Is what I have done incorrect?

Comment: You need to take the derivative of the X(x) before plugging in the value as BC suggests.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Thank you very much!